# Unique constraint on multiple columns

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, custom-list, column, splist

I would like to be able to set a unique constraint on two columns to avoid entries like in the 4th record below (1234,B1)

```
ColumnA       ColumnB
1234          B1
1212          A1
3211          B1
1234          B1
```

is it possible to achieve this without using any event handler or workflow?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is something OOB for multiple columns. I would suggest to use JavaScript and override PreSaveAction to prevent the save if the combination exists. Something like that :

```
function PreSaveAction(){
    //get field 1 value
    //get field 2 value
    //perform a query to check if there are items that matches criteria
    if(noresults)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        //show custom error message
        return false;
    }
}
```

*Heads up if you run a REST call as it will run asynchronous and maybe the PreSaveAction will not work as expected. (haven't tested)